# Huge, unnecessary and mysterious scroll bar

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to this [website](http://www.docscorp.com/). And I have no idea why it has this huge scroll. I'm try understand why or where this scroll is created.

Comment: I'm guessing one of the numerous scripts on there (maybe the script thats dynamically positioning the lightbox element? Not sure). But there's a lot of things that might be throwing the site out, like having the entire DOM wrapped in a form. Was this built in a CMS?

Comment: I'm sure the html5-lightbox isn't the problem. I'm suspect about bootstrap. It is built in EPiServer CMS

Comment: it looks to be something in ul.left_menu that's causing it

Comment: This is not really a good question for Stack Overflow. It's not useful to the broader community and is likely to be closed as off-topic.

Comment: That said, it was an interesting mystery. Zero in on the deeply nested `.left_menu li ul`, child of `.nav-path-wrap`.

Comment: @Michael_B I thought the same, when I started to dig though the markup it was like going down a rabbit hole

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this div `.nav-path-wrap` it has `diplay:initial` and on hover you make its `position` `absolute` , it always will have its space on your page even it not visible.

so you just need to make its `display:none` and on hover `display:block`

css must be like this :

```
.left_menu .nav-path-wrap {
    background: url(../images/icons/icon_left_menu_arrow_l.png) no-repeat left 1em;
    padding-left: .7em;
    display: none; // edit this from initial to none
}

.left_menu li:hover .nav-path-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    left: 12em;
    top: -.5em;
    height: 100px;
    display: block; // add this line
}
```

note that if you edited the `.left_menu { overflow: hidden; }`. the sub menu `.nav-path-wrap` will not be visible on hover

Answer (score 0):

```
.left_menu li:hover ul {
    top: -.8em;
    left: .7em;
    display: inline-block;//add
}
.left_menu li ul {
    background: #109CD8;
    z-index: 100;
    display: none;//change
    height: auto;
    padding: .3em 1em 1em 1.4em;
    left: -999em;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 0px #053047;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 0px #053047;
    width: 14.6em;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

So I've gone through the inspector deleting elements until I came across the culprit.

The `ul.left_menu.clearfix` is what's causing the layout problem. If you remove the `.left_menu` class, the list spills out into a huge vertical list, and the white space disappears.

This isn't the "best" solution, but you can remove that class, add a fixed height, and then set the `overflow-y` to scroll.

You may find a more elegant option though.